# File completion at Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

i'm new to `Webstorm` and i found a weird/bugged behavior.

At few Videos about Webstorm, [i saw people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76fFK-np6GY) using a shortcut for `autocomplete` Filenames inside (for example) an `link` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
```

When i try whats said at that video, i can see the files in my current folder. But when it comes to matching the files that should be allowed inside that `link` tag, i just get "No suggestions".

E.g.: I have a `tree` with these filese:

```
│   index.html
├───css
│       styles.css
```

Inside the `index.html` i want an autocomplete for the `styles.css` at an `link` tag or search files, that would match to the allowed tag.

I tried: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

But the only answer i get when i try it that way is:

[image]

While researching, i found some forum threads where a related problem occured and it could be fixed with `Invalidate` the Cache. But it's not working anyway.

Maybe i accidentally disabled that function or misconfigured something and its broken now.

Hopefully you can give me a solution `:)`

Comment: the path here is relative to index.html; you need to enter the folder name (css) - the completion will suggest files in this folder

Comment: this works. but its possible, to let webstorm find that files recursivly.

Comment: not possible currently, please vote for [WEB-7566](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7566)

Comment: i though this was implemented. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hey @lena, after installing Version 8 ( which seems to be released few hours ago), its working now :D - Pretty happy about that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed at Version 8. Otherwise Issue [WEB-7566](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7566) is a good way to look at - Thanks [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

With Webstorm8 on mac, this issue has not been resolved with regards to src attributes inside script tags

Answer (score 0):

I still have this issue on version 8.0.4.

However there's a little workaround : 
if you try to enter the path without the quotes the auto-completion seems to work (at lease for me):

[image]